# modification of bootstrap multi select plugin for List Box

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I've used `bootstrap multi select plugin` for multiple selection. I have taken reference from https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Multiple-Select-MultiSelect-DropDownList-with-CheckBoxes-in-ASPNet-using-jQuery.aspx. I want to modify some CSS effects of this plugin.

For example, I've got 9 options in my drop down list. When I select 3 options from the list, it shows the item name but if I select more than that, it shows only the number of options selected. I've given `col-md-12` for this list box but still it does not display more than 3 items names.

Also how to increase the lenght of the list box control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these can be answered by looking at the [documentation](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/), which should have been the first thing you did.

From the documentation:

1: [Changing number of options shown before "n selected" message](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-numberDisplayed):

```
$('#example-numberDisplayed').multiselect({
     numberDisplayed: 1
});
```

2: [Changing button width](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-buttonWidth):

```
$('#example-buttonWidth-overflow').multiselect({
     buttonWidth: '150px'
});
```